# How to access class variable in method when class and class method have same variable with name also?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am unable to access class variable in method of same class and my method also having same name of class variable

```
class x(object):
    x = 10    # class variable
    def method1(self,v1):
       x = v1   # method variable
       # here I want to access class variable
```

Comment: Simply use `self.x`. If you want to be explicit you can use `x.x`.

Comment: BTW, it's probably poor style to use local variables with the same names as class variables, it makes things confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you understand the difference between class variable, instance variable and local variable.

```
class Test:
x = 10 //class variable or static variable; shared by all objects
def __init__(self):
    self.x = 20 //instance variable; different value for each object
def func(self, x): //method variable
    print Test.x
    print self.x
    print x
```

Output:

10
20
30
Test.x prints the static varible. To use instance variable you have to use self.instance_variable and you can directly use the local variable by its name inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as follows!
As Barmar mentioned, it isnt a good practice to use the same name for class and class variable!

```
>>> class x():
...     def method(self, v1):
...             self.x = v1
...             print self.x
...
>>> y = x()
>>> y.method(5)
5
>>> y.x
5
```